# Help needed from Expect/ExpectJ experts

Tags: java, shell, expect

Lets say i have the following shellscript **details.sh**

```
echo "name"
read name
if [ "$name" == "abcd" ]; then
echo "hi"
echo "hello"
echo "bye"
fi
```

=============================================

And this is my Java code

```
ExpectJ exp = new ExpectJ();
String cmd = "sh details.sh"; //Command for execution of **details.sh**
Spawn s = exp.spawn(cmd); //Spawns the process **details.sh**
s.expect("name");  //Expecting "name" from the script
s.send("abcd");  //When successful, it sends **abcd** as the input to the script

//Now the script will compare the input(given by java code) with the pre-fed one (the one in the script)

s.expect("hi");  //according to me only **hi** must be displayed,but the java console is taking and displaying all the consecutive echo statements from the script.
```

Any idea why that's happening?Or is it supposed to behave that way only?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok it would display the same strings even though u only one of them. It displays all those strings which are consecutive. I've learnt that its the natural behavior of **expectj.Spawn.expect()**. That's how it works.

In this case, even if i put-

s.expect("hi");

the output i'll get will be-

hi
hello
bye

So there is nothing to be worried about.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your script output, I would put in the following expect

```
s.expect("hi\nhello\nbye");
```